# Pandas pivot_table datetime wrongly ordered

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here is the partial output of a `dataframe`

```
                      Date     Value     Entity
0     01/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.778447      Aag
1     02/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.680482      Aag
2     03/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.574833      Aag
3     04/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.461546      Aag
4     05/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.340676      Aag
5     06/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.212280      Aag
6     07/01/2016, 10:30:00  110.076422      Aag
```

When i apply `pd.pivot_table` to this `dataframe`

`results = pd.pivot_table(dataframe1, values='Value', index=['Date'], columns=['Entity'], aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)`

i am getting a weirdly sorted `date` like below

```
Date                                             ...                            
01/01/2016, 10:30:00  
01/02/2016, 10:30:00  
01/03/2016, 10:30:00  
01/04/2016, 10:30:00  
01/05/2016, 10:30:00  
01/06/2016, 10:30:00  
01/07/2016, 10:30:00  
01/08/2016, 10:30:00  
01/09/2016, 10:30:00  
01/10/2016, 10:30:00  
01/11/2016, 10:30:00  
01/12/2016, 10:30:00  
02/01/2016, 10:30:00  
02/02/2016, 10:30:00  
02/03/2016, 10:30:00
```

What am i missing here, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @MrFuppes it worked, thanks, please add this as answer

Comment: glad it helped, added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output you get looks like it's ordered by the string characters - parse the column to datetime dtype with the appropriate format before pivot, e.g.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
```